# Remove files from Bazaar

Tags: php, linux, bazaar

I'm using Bazaar (`bzr`) to keep source code for a website updated, but we've ran into a problem when we remove files from version control. The files we are removing are ones we never intended to version to begin with.

When this happens we use `bzr rm --keep` to remove the file from version control, but keep the file in the file system. Doing a `bzr push` or `bzr pull` results in the removed file(s) being removed on the other branches (other sites that use our code)

We need a way to make sure that a `bzr push` or `bzr pull` doesn't actually remove those from the working copy. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `bzr rm --keep` in all locations manually before updating them with `pull`/`push`. There is no other way unfortunately.